# - clean start eclipse in ubuntu from terminal

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, terminal

I am using ubuntu I have two eclipse I am unable to clean one eclipse . .how to -clean start specific eclipse in ubuntu from command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to do something like this :

```
/full/path/to/first/eclipse -clean
```

and,

```
/full/path/to/second/eclipse -clean
```

There are a number of ways to find out the full path of eclipse installations.

**Method 1 - Find**

You should be able to find the eclipse installations by using the following command :

```
find / -iname "eclipse"  | grep -iE "eclipse$" | grep -i bin
```

**Method 2 - Ubuntu specific**

1. First, from the list of installed packages find the package names which contain the word *eclipse* :

   ```
   sudo  dpkg-query -Wf  '${Installed-Size}t${Package}n' | sort -n | grep -i eclipse
   ```
2. Then, for each of the results from the above command, do the following :

   ```
   dpkg -L <package_name_from_above> | grep -i bin
   ```

The command above should give you the paths to the eclipse installations which can then be suffixed by an `-clean`

### Update - Ubuntu Specific Method

I had been meaning to take a look at what the latest release of Ubuntu had to offer and this gave me the perfect excuse to setup an Ubuntu VM :)

The following commands were executed on a default install of Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop and are slightly different from what I wrote above. In all of the following commands replace *zip* with ***eclipse*** :

1. Find the packages which contain eclipse :

   ```
   dpkg-query -Wf  '${Package}\n' | grep eclipse
   ```
2. Find the path of the eclipse binary :

   ```
   dpkg -L eclipse | grep bin | grep -iE "eclipse$"
   ```

To make is easier to do the above, I created a script with the following code :

```
#! /bin/bash

echo
echo "The possible executable paths contained in $1 package are : "
echo
dpkg-query -Wf  '${Package}\n' | grep -i "$1" | xargs -I % dpkg -L % | grep bin | grep -iE "$1$"

#Echo a blank line
echo
```

It takes only one argument, the package name for which you want to search the executable. Copy the code above into a file called `sue.sh` (Search Ubuntu Executable :) ) and do a `chmod +x ./sue.sh`

Example executions : 
`./sue.sh eclipse`
[image]

`./sue.sh zip`
[image]